# Picky on Getter/Setter name? JSF/Jboss Seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I'm working on a JBoss seam application (JSF 1.1 and MyFaces Tomahawk) which runs on tomcat 5.0.28.

What is bugging me is that at times when i create a variable and the setter and getter for it they don't get picked up resutling in me getting errors like:

```
 javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Bean: com.sportsMed.Util , property: mappingUID
```

I have to try and change the Setter/Getter name repeatedly and test until it passes through without errors and this can be going through 5-6 different names and becomes such a waste of time.

Am i doing something wrong? Just 10 minutes ago i had to change:

```
  private String UserName;
  public void setUserName(String s)...
  public String getUserName()....
```

that didn't work resulting in Property not found so i changed the above to:

```
  private String user_Name;
  public void setuser_Name(String s)...
  public String getuser_Name()....
```

Nope and finally tried:

```
  private String nUser;
  public void setnUser(String s)...
  public String getnUser()....
```

Somehow that works fine! and as mentioned at times it won't work until 5-6 name changes! Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why its happening. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- field must be lower-case, without underscores
- setter must be `set` + capitalized field (same for getter)

So:

```
private String userName;
public void setUserName(..);
public String getUserName(..);
```

Reference: [javabeans spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html), [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Using an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ) to generate the setters and getters would make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for your input Bozho, Can you by any chance provide a link where this is referenced from, thanks

Comment: yup, see my updated answer. The javabeans spec is a bit hard to read, but if you really need to see that my statement is correct - read it :)