# h:selectOneMenu a4j:support action being executed hundreds of time

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectColumn" value="#{EquipReportBean.columnFilter}" required="false">
    <s:selectItems value="#{EquipReportBean.all_columns}" var="t"  label="#{t.name}" hideNoSelectionLabel="false" noSelectionLabel="Please Select..." />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{EquipReportBean.loadFilterFields}" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="divString,divSelect,divDateStart,divDateEnd"/>
    <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the code of my selectOneMenu. The problem is with the action inside a4j:support. The action is being triggered hundreds of times and taking about 5 seconds to conclude and I don't understand why. To compare the speed, I created a separated button to run this action, and it worked instantly. Maybe it's a simple question, but I can't find the solution on the internet for this, or maybe I am searching for the wrong words.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related, but you should avoid getters like :

```
#{EquipReportBean.all_columns}

public List<> getAll_columns()
{

}
```

and replace it like this :

```
#{EquipReportBean.allColumns}

public List<> getAllColumns()
{

}
```

**More info :**

- [Picky on Getter/Setter name? JSF/Jboss Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702153/354831)