# How to recharge a primefaces component after successful login with ajax behaviour

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to recharge the same primefaces component after an successful login with ajax behaviour, but I don't know how to do this. The recharged component must show the complete name of the user which is recovered by an hibernate dao from the DB and the input boxes for user and password must desappear.

**View :**

```
<h:head> 
    <title>header layout</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:panelGrid id="loginPanelGrid">      
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText value="#{loginManagedBean.username}" id="username" required="true" label="username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <p:password value="#{loginManagedBean.password}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />
        </h:form>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" update="okLoginPanelGrid" action="#{loginManagedBean.login(actionEvent)}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:panelGrid id="okLoginPanelGrid">                
        <h:outputText id="clienteLogado" value="#{loginManagedBean.loggedClient}" />
    </p:panelGrid>   
</h:body>
```

**Bean :**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginManagedBean implements Serializable{

private String username;
private String password;

private Cliente loggedClient;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{clienteDAO}")
private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if( (this.getUsername() != null && !this.getUsername().isEmpty()) && 
        (this.getPassword() != null && !this.getPassword().isEmpty()) ){

        List<Cliente> clienteLogin = clienteDAO.comprobarLogin(username, password);

        if(clienteLogin != null && clienteLogin.size() > 0){ 
            loggedClient = new Cliente();
            for(Cliente client : clienteLogin){
                loggedClient.setCliente_nombre(client.getCliente_nombre());
                loggedClient.setCliente_apellido1(client.getCliente_apellido1());
                loggedClient.setCliente_apellido2(client.getCliente_apellido2());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("**** There are NO CLIENTS for this user and password selected ****");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("**** user or password NOT RECOVERED ****");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `update=":okLoginPanelGrid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `h:form` to encapsulate the `p:commandButton`. That prevent your `p:commandButton` to submit anything to the bean. You should add it like this :

```
<h:body>
    <h:panelGrid id="login-panel">
        <h:form rendered="#{loginManagedBean.loggedClient eq null}">
            <h:panelGroup id="loginPanelGrid">      
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{loginManagedBean.username}" id="username" required="true" label="username" />

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                <p:password value="#{loginManagedBean.password}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" update="login-panel" action="#{loginManagedBean.login(actionEvent)}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>

        <p:panelGroup rendered="#{loginManagedBean.loggedClient ne null}" id="okLoginPanelGrid">                
            <h:outputText id="clienteLogado" value="#{loginManagedBean.loggedClient.client_name}" />
        </p:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:body>
```

**Not related :**

I would also say the shorter a bean lives, the better your memory usage will be. In that way, the bean `LoginManagedBean` don't need to be `SessionScoped`, it could even be only `RequestScoped` if you move your property `loggedClient` to a SessionScoped attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I tried it but the login form remains in the view.

Comment: @JoseAntonio1984 sorry missed that part, I've modified the answer accordingly!

Comment: I edited you answer code on the update of the commandButton and the value of the outputText because loggedClient is an Object, for show only the name in this testing. I Debbuged the app and loggedClient Object have his name, surname,... but the login form remains in the view after a correct login.

Comment: @JoseAntonio1984 My error, I've not changed the `update` attribute properly, now it is!

Comment: Now on successful login the login form disappears, but for some reason the second panelGrid that contains the client data isn't show.

Comment: @JoseAntonio1984 Probably something to do with your getter `loggedClient.client_name`, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7702153/354831)

Comment: On your answer code, a panelGrid must wrap the panelGroups and works perfectly!!! Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: @JoseAntonio1984 I'm not sure to understand what panelGroups must be wrapped by panelGrid but good :)

Comment: I saw this way in this example: [link](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGroup.html)